# Use xindy to sort by bible book instead of ABC – or: How to add custom letter groups?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I try to generate an index which entries are not group by normal letters A, B, C, … but by books of the bible eg. Num, Dtn, Ps etc. So my question is **how can I define a custom list of letter groups based on the books of the bible**. As far as I understand the `xindy` manual all I have to do is to add some new letter groups with `define-letter-groups` in a custom style file, but my attempt failed.

This is my M(not)WE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\begin{filecontents}{index-style.xdy}
(require "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy")
(require "texindy.xdy")

(require "page-ranges.xdy")
(require "book-order.xdy")

(markup-locclass-list :open ": ")

(define-letter-groups ("Num"  "Dtn" "Ps"))
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a6paper,DIV=20]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[options = -M index-style -C utf8]

\begin{document}
   Test
   \index{Ps 1}
   \index{Ps 10}
   \index{Ps 2}
   \index{Ps 1}
   \index{Ps 3}
   \index{Ps 56}
   \index{Ps 5}
   \index{Ps 34,1--2}
   \index{Ps 34,7}
   \index{Ps 34,1}
   \index{Ps 34|full}
   \index{Ps 34}
   \index{Dtn 3,7.9}
   \index{Dtn 3,5}
   \index{Dtn 3,8}
   \index{Num 122,3}
   \index{Num 121}
   \printindex
\end{document}
```

The `xindy` manual unfornutalty isn’t really details about letter groups and as far is I can tell I did nothing wrong in my style file, but I fear im missing something important.

What I found here on TeX.SX:

- **[xindy : how to add new letters and lettergroups to the alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17890/4918)** has an two answers but only for the special problem of adding groups for the Pali language. I’m not able to understand the [first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172205/4918) and transfer it to my problem. The [second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17960/4918) is a little less complicated but it doesn’t even work if I try to reproduce the results from there if I follow the steps one by one. I.e. the code – which is from 2011 – seems not to work.
- The answer for **[Xindy doesn't sort keywords properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240791/4918)** suggest that I have to define a new language first. Is this true? Then why isn’t that mentioned in the `xindy` manual …?
- **[Index of bible verses with xindy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332701/4918)** has answers but no real solution …
- The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344916/4918) on **[xindy: rule to remove index entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344836/4918)** also uses a custom letter group but additionally with a strange (what kind of special sequence is `~b`?) merge rule. However it seems to be a *workaround* if I use prefixes that aren’t normal letters:

  ```
  (define-letter-groups ("Num" "Dtn" "Ps"))

  (define-letter-group "Dtn" :prefixes ("#"))
  (merge-rule "^Dtn" "#")

  (define-letter-group "Num" :prefixes ("@"))
  (merge-rule "^Num" "@")

  (define-letter-group "Ps" :prefixes ("<"))
  (merge-rule "^Ps" "<")
  ```

  But this can’t be the intended solution …
- The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313395/4918) on **[Strange sorting of Greek letters using glossaries with xindy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312768/4918)** uses new letter groups for greek letters and in that case no merge rule are used.

The last two questions led me to the theory that the problem with my letter groups is that they consist only of normal letters and are ignored because there are already groups for normal letters. However the `xindy` manual says

> More problems arise when using languages with different letter schemes. Hungarian is an example. In Hungarian indexes the words beginning with the letters Cs, Ly, Ny and more are printed in a separate block. The words beginning with Ly, for example, appear behind the words beginning with an L. xindy allows to define this kind of letter groups as well. Add the following lines to the style file.
>
> ```
>      (define-letter-group "ly" :after "l" :before "m")
>      (define-letter-group "ny" :after "n" :before "o")
>
>      (markup-letter-group :open-head "~n {\bf " :close-head "}"
>                          :capitalize)
> ```

Which is obviously an example with only letters …

---

Another *workaround* is to only use merge rules and map each book to a letter of the alphabet and then add some TeX code to transform `\lettergroup{A}` to output **Num**.

---

**Edit:** Please consider the bible books only as *one* example for the usage of new letter groups. I’m not looking for further workarounds to typeset/index the bible books, but a **general solution on how to define letter groups with `xindy`**.

Comment: Imho xindy has some rather serious flaws -- including bad documentation, no real utf8 support and bad integration in the tlmgr structure. The curious prefixes used for the sorting are one indication of the unsolved problems. Do you really need to use it? Can't you use glossaries?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I thought it was developed for use with native Unicode support and had no problems with this. The other flaws are there – unfortunately. I’m not bound to `xindy` but i found it’s style system a bit more intuitive and flexible than the one of `makeindex.` and glossaries uses `makeindex` or `xindy` in the background doesn’t it? I never used it before …

Comment: "No real utf8" was a bit harsh, but xindy was developed at a time when most pdflatex users still used 8-bit encoding and so e.g. the utf8.xdy are 8-bit encoded and not utf8. Nicola is currently trying to develop a tool for glossaries, I saw the announcement.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Hm … I give this question another try on the `xindy` mailing list. Does anybody know if the development is still active?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/mailman/xindy-discuss/?viewmonth=201701

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks … the sourceforge page was unavailable for me earlier … I posted at the mailing list now (not yet visible in the archive)

Comment: Here’s the ailing list thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/mailman/message/35703977/

Comment: I know nothing about xindy but I've seen a mention of it here: is this of any help to you? https://cikitsa.blogspot.com/2016/07/getting-xindy-to-work-for-iast-encoded.html

Comment: Hi @ShreevatsaR: Thanks for the link, but this is about sorting rules for unknown letters and doesn’t provided any help for my question unfortunately …

Comment: From the question, it seems that you already have a bunch of solutions; it's not clear why they can't be used. For example, why not define a new language? Surely a language whose “letters” are {Ps, Dtn, Num, …} is different from English.

Comment: I think you have to use `make-rules.pl` (which will generate rules like `(define-rule-set "pi-alphabetize" ...`); it's not enough to just define the letter groups.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The solutions in my question are only workarounds ;-) and I like a clean solution. The problem here is basically that the manual gives a non-working guide and I want to know it the manual is wrong or only me getting it wrong / missing something. Furthermore I don’t believe I have to use make-rules or define a new language (this would be another work-around, I’d say) because in fact it is enough to define new letter groups when they use non-latin characters …

Comment: The (german) TeX companion also does only mention the `define-letter-group` solution without the need for an additional script-use / new language. It clearly says that an entry is sorted in the letter group with the longest match (“Dtn 1,2--3” in group `Dtn`, not in group `D`).

Comment: Quite likely the documentation is just wrong or outdated -- in fact the observation that it doesn't work looks like evidence that the documentation is wrong :-)

Comment: My current hypothesis is that `define-letter-group` is documentation for those who are writing a language file. And xindy picks up letter groups from the language file. BTW http://xindy.sourceforge.net/documentation.html starts with “ Documentation is one of our big problems in this project” :-)

Comment: BTW I think I figured out the issue: the file `texmf-dist/xindy/modules/lang/general/utf8.xdy` (or `latin9.xdy`) defines letter groups like `(define-letter-group "D" :after "C" :prefixes ("\219"))` (here `\219` denotes the byte 219 in octal = 8d in hex = 141 in decimal). So input like "Dtn" becomes "\215\332\274". I was able to `(define-letter-group "DtnOctal" :prefixes ("\215\332\274") :after "C")` (don't copy this, replace `\215` etc. with the actual characters) and get a "Dtn" letter group in the index (separate from "D").

Comment: I can also confirm that if I suppress `utf8-lang.xdy` from being loaded (by hacking the `xindy.run` command that gets called), then I get the group `Dtn` to work with just plain ascii. Of course, then I have to define all the other letter groups I want (like "A", "B", "C" etc) explicitly.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Thanks for your investigation! If you made an answer out of it I could accept and award the bounty (unfortunately theres is not much time until the bounty grace period expires …). Back to the topic: Where do I have to put the line with the `DtnOctal` definition. I can’t make it work in the index style file …

Comment: I will try to post an answer later tonight (in three hours or so).

Comment: Took twice as long; have added it now :-)

Comment: I finally understood what's happening, and found an alternative solution, which is to specify the language as Klingon :-) Have edited my answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR. Many thanks. I’ll take a look at it later and then accept it too ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [Klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language): change the line

```
\makeindex[options = -M index-style -C utf8]
```

in your TeX file to

```
\makeindex[options = -M index-style -C utf8 -L klingon]
```

This produces a PDF file whose index page is typeset as:

[image: Properly typeset index]

which I believe is what you wanted.

---

Long answer:

This one was, for me, a good lesson in software testing: I had to treat the `xindy` program almost as a black-box, because its documentation is terrible and even actively misleading. In fact, of all the time I spent trying to figure this out, the biggest leap towards a solution was the moment I decided to completely stop trusting the documentation.

The following is not exactly how I arrived at the solution/understanding, but a lightly “fictionalized account” of how one *might* have.

To recap the question: After saving the LaTeX source from the question as `question.tex`, changing `filecontents` to `filecontents*` (so that it doesn't write `%%` comments to the file), and running `xelatex -shell-escape question.tex` (note: `shell-escape` is in general dangerous; you should not use that option without being absolutely sure the file is safe to run), we get a typeset PDF whose index page looks like the following:

[image: bad index]

So the problem is that it seems to have completely ignored the `(define-letter-groups ...` in the index style.

If you look in the log file (`question.log`), it mentions the program that was invoked:

```
runsystem(texindy -M index-style -C utf8 question.idx)...executed.
```

And you can verify for yourself that it is this command (`texindy -M index-style -C utf8 question.idx`) that turns `question.idx`:

```
\indexentry{Ps 1}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 10}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 2}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 1}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 3}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 56}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 5}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 34,1--2}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 34,7}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 34,1}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 34|full}{1}
\indexentry{Ps 34}{1}
\indexentry{Dtn 3,7.9}{1}
\indexentry{Dtn 3,5}{1}
\indexentry{Dtn 3,8}{1}
\indexentry{Num 122,3}{1}
\indexentry{Num 121}{1}
```

into `question.ind`:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{D}
  \item Dtn 3,5: 1
  \item Dtn 3,7.9: 1
  \item Dtn 3,8: 1

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{N}
  \item Num 121: 1
  \item Num 122,3: 1

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{P}
  \item Ps 1: 1
  \item Ps 2: 1
  \item Ps 3: 1
  \item Ps 5: 1
  \item Ps 10: 1
  \item Ps 34: 1
  \item Ps 34,1: 1
  \item Ps 34,1--2: 1
  \item Ps 34,7: 1
  \item Ps 56: 1

\end{theindex}
```

The bug already manifests here. So at this point we can forget about the TeX stuff and focus on getting the desired `question.ind` out of the `question.idx` using the `texindy` (or another) command.

The `texindy` command has some debug options. For example, adding `--debug script` shows that `texindy` is essentially calling `xindy` as `xindy -d script -L general -C utf8 -M tex/inputenc/utf8 -M texindy -M page-ranges -M word-order -M index-style.xdy -I latex question.idx`. We can run that directly, and see that it produces the same output (the “bad” `question.ind`).

This list of modules automatically included by `texindy` also suggests that some of the lines of our `index-style.xdy` are redundant: we can boil it down to just

```
(markup-locclass-list :open ": ")
(define-letter-groups ("Num"  "Dtn" "Ps"))
```

and keep the output the same. We can go further and also reduce the `xindy` command to `xindy -M texindy -M index-style question.idx`. Now we can run `xindy` directly, instead of `texindy`.

To continue exploring the debug options, the first thing is to have `xindy` log to a file instead of throwing it away (to `/dev/null`). This is done with `-t question.ilg`. This log file has output like

```
Forming letter-groups:
Letter-group: "?? 0000001" -> "P"
Letter-group: "?? 0000010" -> "P"
```

and so on, which clearly correspond one-to-one with the lines from the input (`question.idx`). (`??` is what it displays as in my terminal, but I can open it up in a editor to see the actual bytes: e.g. `less` shows the second line as `Letter-group: "<C8><D0> 0000010" -> "P"` with those two characters higlighted.)

So, for some reason, it has converted input entry like `\indexentry{Ps 10}{1}` into `"<C8><D0> 0000010"`, which then gets mapped to letter group `P`.

The `--debug level=1` (or higher) option to `xindy` has something relevant in the log: lines like

```
Add sort rule to run 0: #<ordrule: '<E4>' => '<80>' :again NIL>
Add sort rule to run 0: #<ordrule: 'A' => '<80>' :again NIL>
...
Add sort rule to run 0: #<ordrule: 'p' => '<C8>' :again NIL>
Add sort rule to run 0: #<ordrule: 'P' => '<C8>' :again NIL>
```

and so on. But this still doesn't explain where those sort rules are coming from. With the remaining debug options `--debug script --debug keep_tmpfiles` though, we can find out: First, the command uses a filter called `tex2xindy` to convert our `.idx` file into a file that has lines like:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("Ps 1")) :locref "1")
(indexentry :tkey (("Ps 10")) :locref "1")
```

(entirely in Lisp syntax). This file, we will soon learn, is called the "rawindex". Then, the “core” of xindy runs with a command like:

```
xindy.run -M /Library/TeX/texbin/xindy.mem -E iso-8859-1 -x (progn
  (searchpath ".:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/xindy/modules:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base")
  (xindy:startup
    :idxstyle "<tmp file 1>"
    :rawindex "<above tmp file>"
    :output "./question.ind"
    :logfile "question.ilg"

    )
  (exit))
```

We can run this command directly, and see that it (still) produces the same `.ind` file. We're getting close: looking at the tmp file above (the attribute `:idxstyle`), it looks like:

```
(require "lang/general/latin9-lang.xdy")
(require "texindy.xdy")
(require "index-style.xdy")
```

The last two (of the three) lines were specified manually by our commandline `xindy -M texindy -M index-style`; the first one was inserted automatically by xindy. (The `latin9` does not matter here; if we had used `-C utf8` we'd get `lang/general/utf8-lang.xdy` here in which the problems are the same.) Looking inside that file (`texmf-dist/xindy/modules/lang/general/latin9-lang.xdy`), it starts with

```
(require "lang/general/latin9.xdy")
```

and *that* file starts with lines like:

```
(define-letter-group "A" :prefixes ("<80>"))
(define-letter-group "B" :after "A" :prefixes ("<84>"))
(define-letter-group "C" :after "B" :prefixes ("<86>"))
(define-letter-group "D" :after "C" :prefixes ("<8D>"))
```

which give a hint as to what's going on: already by the time `define-letter-group` is involved, the characters have already been transformed into bytes like `"<80>"` (recall the log lines like `Add sort rule to run 0: #<ordrule: 'A' => '<80>' :again NIL>` that we saw earlier). So these `define-letter-group` commands are operating not on the raw input in the index file, but on these transformed bytes.

At this point, we can just use the same byte replacements as in this file, to get **Solution 1**: Create the file `index-style.xdy` whose contents are lightly modified from your original, using the following Python script:

```py
s = '''
(markup-locclass-list :open ": ")

(define-letter-group "Num" :prefixes ("\xbc\xe0\xbb"))
(define-letter-group "Dtn" :prefixes ("\x8d\xda\xbc") :after "Num")
(define-letter-group "Ps" :prefixes ("\xc8\xd0") :after "Dtn")
'''

open('index-style.xdy', 'w').write(s)
```

(This Python script just assigns the file contents as a string to the variable `s` and writes out that variable to the file `index-style.xdy`: you can use any language or even a shell script; the goal is just to get binary data into the file.)

Then using this `index-style.xdy` gives the index you desired (and which is in the screenshot above).

The explanation, for *why* these transformations happen, is lower in the same file (now I'm using `utf8.xdy` instead of `latin9.xdy`):

```
(define-rule-set "xy-alphabetize"

  :rules  (("À" "<80>" :string)
           ("Ă" "<80>" :string)
           ("â" "<80>" :string)
...
           ("A" "<80>" :string)
...
           ))
```

and this rule-set is used in `utf8-lang.xdy`:

```
(use-rule-set :run 0
              :rule-set ("xy-alphabetize" "xy-ignore-special"))
```

because of which in the very first (0th) run, all the characters are transformed already, which is why our `(define-letter-groups ("Num"  "Dtn" "Ps"))` did not work. The documentation is correct about `(define-letter-groups ...)`, in the sense that the feature really exists and the core of `xindy` supports it. However, the default “general” configuration (which by the way, is documented in the file comments as “A general sorting order for Western European languages”), explicitly does some stuff that gets in the way, and the documentation says nothing about dealing with this.

If they had provided instead of “general” a “bare” “language” that is even more minimal than “general” (and does not do the hackery with translating characters to bytes outside the ascii range), then using `(define-letter-groups` with english-alphabet characters would have just worked (as simple as giving `-L bare` or whatever).

To confirm that this is the case, we can pursue an alternative approach (**Solution 2**), of giving an explicit file (without the first line), instead of the temporary file for `idxstyle`. In this file we remove the first `(require "lang/general/latin9-lang.xdy")` line and keep only the requires of `texindy` and our `index-style.xdy`. If we do that, e.g. I put the two lines into a file called `forced-idxstyle` and changed the `xindy.run` command to just

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/xindy.run -M /Library/TeX/texbin/xindy.mem -E iso-8859-1 -x '(progn (searchpath ".:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/xindy/modules:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base") (xindy:startup :idxstyle "./forced-idxstyle" :rawindex "<same tmp file as before>" :output "./question.ind" :logfile "question.ilg") (exit))'
```

it worked: our plain `index-style.xdy` file which had just the two lines

```
(markup-locclass-list :open ": ")
(define-letter-groups ("Num"  "Dtn" "Ps"))
```

now starts giving the exact `question.ind` file we want (and we can run `xelatex` and we'll get the desired typeset output in the index).

This confirms that `define-letter-groups` works as documented, and would have been usable by the end user (us) if not for all the “helpful” transformations done by all of xindy's default languages, for treating accented letters the same as unaccented letters.

Actually not *all*: among the languages that come with `xindy` there are a few that don't work with Latin-script characters, and in particular don't transform "A" (for example) into anything else:

> belarusian bulgarian georgian greek hebrew klingon korean macedonian russian serbian ukrainian

Of these, if you really want a language that will never get in the way when using English, then “korean” is the most promising, because the others (even Klingon which isn't even in Unicode and uses private-area characters!) do transform some “special” characters like hyphens and semicolons. So this gives **Solution 3** that I put at the top of this answer: keep your original index style, keep your original TeX file, just append `-L korean` to the indexing command, and you get the index you desired. (The other languages like Klingon etc. also work.)

Comment: Again: Thank you very much for your research on this topic. Although the “klingon solution” is more or less a workaround and i didn’t wanted to use workarounds, this is the way I go. There’s only one problem: Books like `1 Kor` will be sorted in the default group since even the klingons seem to know how to sort numbers. Therefor I use `I Kor` as group and a `merge-rule` for the `1 Kor` entries.

Comment: @Tobi I ran into the same problem with books starting with a number. It's caused by the merge-rules from `numeric-sort.xdy` (included in `texindy.xdy`, loaded by default by `texindy`), zero-padding every numeral, thus turning `1 Kor` to `0000001 Kor`. I solved it by getting rid of `texindy.xdy` and writing custom zero-padding merge-rules https://github.com/igneus/In-adiutorium/commit/6186f2d9489c5f5f3eafcb7cafa0d2f748201684

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem for my work without using xindy. My alternative was to use sort keys. Thus: `\index{19@Psalms!0901 @9:1}`. `19` is Psalms' order in the Hebrew Bible, so this number before the `@` sign sorts the books in correct order. The exclamation point (`!`) makes the book itself, Psalms, the item and verses will be indexed as subitems below it. You can just remove this if you want the book title before every citation. `0901` is the sort code for 9:1 with zeroes preventing chapters from 10 (example: 11:1) being listed first. The space prevents a verse range from appearing before single verses, so `0901_` will sort ahead of `0901-07`. (This is a genius insight of Barbara Beeton's from [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/index-sorting-where-numbers-are-indexed)).

If you have `\index{05@Deuteronomy!1212 @12:12} \index{02@Exodus!0101-12@1:1-12} \index{19@Psalms!0901 @9:1}` this should now result in correct biblical order. So:

Exodus

1:1-12

Deuteronomy

12:12

Psalms

9:1

I preferred this solution myself. You may also want to check out [the bibleref pacakage](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref/bibleref.pdf) too. I haven't used it, but I believe it can work with indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need a solution without manual sort keys (there are lots of index entries, which can’t be redone manually …). `bibleref` would also nee too much manual changes (the book is finished) and furthermore doesn’t seem to support things like _Ps 90(91),1.4_.

Comment: Fair enough. My book was also already done. Do I understand correctly that all the citations are already indexed in the form cited in your example? If you can't use xindy in the end, you can use find and replace to change the indexing code: `\index{Dtn 3,8}` can be changed to `\index{04@Deuteronomy 3,8}` without too much trouble, as backwards as such a fix may be. Hopefully it won't come to something like that! Looking forward to seeing other answers to this problem.

Comment: Sure I can do a lot by searcher an replace even dynamically. But I want to know _why_ the new letter groups don’t work and my example is just one application for this …