# How to add custom letter groups to an index, e.g. for greek letters or brackets?

Tags: indexing, greek, sorting, xindy, makeindex

I have an index of symbols made using `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Text

\index{sin@$\sin$}    % just some examples of index entries
\index{cos@$\cos$}
\index{tan@$\tan$}

\index{greek.a@$\alpha$}    % symbols with greek letters
\index{greek.b@$\beta_{x,y}$}

\index{(@$(a)_n$}    % an entry with a bracket

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I would like to have a letter group (subdivision) of the index for each Greek letter. (I understand I would have to specify another key and `greek.a` isn't going to work.) But not just for Greek letters. I also want to organize the entries under the symbols heading, for example gather those that involve round brackets `()`.

**Question:** How can I add custom letter groups to an index? (It doesn't need to be with `makeindex`.)

Comment: It appears this can be done with xindy, although I'm not sure...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356285

Comment: Don't you need `\makeindex`? Otherwise, I get no index at all.

Comment: @cfr yes; of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for MikTeX, I don't know about TeXLive. It can be done with `xindy`. My `.xdy` file begins:

```
(define-letter-group "$\alpha$" :after "default" :before "A" :prefixes ("\235\313\227\227\256\200\264\310\244\200"))
(define-letter-group "$\beta$" :after "$\alpha$" :before "A" :prefixes ("\235\313\227\227\256\204\227\332\200"))
```

where those numbers are octal codes for "greekalpha" resp. "greekbeta" (you can choose any string you think makes sense) which I entered in Emacs not as strings but as single bites, using `M-x hexl-mode C-M-o 235` etc. You can't copy them from another file, but you can copy (or find and replace) them in normal mode within the same file. The numbers themselves I got from `...\xindy\modules\lang\english\utf8.xdy`. If you're having problems, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436632/35468) may help.

I then wrapped everything by defining `\newcommand\greekindex[1]{\index{greek#1}}` so that I can use

```
\greekindex{alpha@$\alpha$}
\greekindex{beta@$\beta_{x,y}$}
```

Note that I compile with

```
xindy -C utf8 -L english -M texindy -M mystylefile myfile.idx
```

I also used package `bm` and as headings I wrote `\bm\alpha` etc: Just change `$\alpha$` in the `.xdy` file to `$\bm\alpha$`.