# How to make xindy not just read but also apply an .xdy style file?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I'm testing `xindy` with MikTeX on Windows 10. I have the following simple `myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some text
\index{aa}
\index{ab}
\index{ac}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

... and `mystyle.xdy` containing one line: `(define-letter-group "ab" :after "A" :before "B")`.

When I run either

```
xelatex myfile
texindy -C utf8 -L english -M mystyle -o myfile.ind myfile.idx
xelatex myfile
```

or

```
xelatex myfile
xindy -C utf8 -L english -M texindy -M mystyle -o myfile.ind myfile.idx
xelatex myfile
```

I can see that `xindy` runs and produces an `.ind`, and it reads my style file but it doesn't apply it. What is going on? How do I make `xindy` apply my style file?

Comment: I didn't test, but perhaps the answer here can help you to debug it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356285/use-xindy-to-sort-by-bible-book-instead-of-abc-or-how-to-add-custom-letter-gr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell definitely about MikTeX, but on my TeXLive on a Debian GNU/Linux system `xindy` uses so called prefixes to put accented letters into lettergroups and to sort them. For example, the following is taken from `/usr/share/xindy/lang/english/utf8.xdy`:

```
;; Rules for xindy; generated by make-rules.pl
;; language: English

(define-letter-group "A" :prefixes ("�"))
(define-letter-group "B" :after "A" :prefixes ("�"))
(define-letter-group "C" :after "B" :prefixes ("�"))
```

(Here `"�"` replaces one-byte strings which are used then to sort index entries, they are different for all lettergroups, for `"A"` it's the `0x80` byte, for `"B"` it's `0x84`, for `"C"` it's `0x86` etc.) After that the `"en-alphabetize"` rule replaces all letters by these prefixes and `xindy` does the sorting and putting words to letergroups based on them. Here is an excerpt from the rule:

```
(define-rule-set "en-alphabetize"

  :rules  (("À" "�" :string)
           ("à" "�" :string)
           ("Æ" "��" :string)
           ("æ" "��" :string)
```

Again, I can't reproduce the 8-bit strings, though the first `"�"` in all four rules is `0x80` which means that these letters will go to the `"A"` lettergroup.

So, If you want your `"AB"` lettergroup to blend in the existing groups, you'll have to assign suitable prefix for it. What works with my TeXLive is the following `mystyle.xdy`:

```
(define-letter-group "ab" :after "A" :prefixes ("��"))
```

where the first `�` has the `0x80` hex code, and the second one has the `0x84` hex code. I don't know if the codes should be the same for MikTeX, as they are generated by a script. Here is the `base64` encoded `mystyle.xdy` if it helps (as simple copying and pasting wouldn't work because of 8-bit strings):

```
KGRlZmluZS1sZXR0ZXItZ3JvdXAgImFiIiA6YWZ0ZXIgIkEiIDpwcmVmaXhlcyAoIoCEIikpDQoNCg==
```

When I run

```
xindy -C utf8 -L english -M texindy -M mystyle myfile.idx
```

I get the following `myfile.ind`:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{A}
  \item aa, 1
  \item ac, 1

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ab}
  \item ab, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: I found the following lines in `lang/english/utf8.xdy`: `(define-letter-group "A" :prefixes ("\200"))   (define-letter-group "B" :after "A" :prefixes ("\204")) 
  (define-letter-group "C" :after "B" :prefixes ("\206"))` so will try with those

Comment: In fact those spaces in `:prefixes` aren't spaces. They are some invisible characters, which you'll have to copy to your `mystyle.xdy` somehow.

Comment: Edited my comment. Actually they are not 4-character strings like "\200" etc but in my Emacs they appear as single characters

Comment: Yes, they aren't escape sequences. They are actual bytes.

Comment: And since they are the same as in my TeXLive distribution, you can unbase64 the style file from the answer. It should work for you as well.

Comment: Those numbers are their octal codes; I managed to insert them using `M-x hexl-mode` `C-M-o`